# Google TV emulator doesn't support local playback and sdcard?

Tags: android, google-tv

I was trying to run local video playback from my application in Google TV emulator, 
               - Does the Google TV emulator support local video playback (MP4)
               - Why isn't there any sdcard support for GTV emulator?

Answer (score 1):

Probably because the Google TV's don't have a SDCard slot?

Comment: True, but there are so many other usercases for secondary storage devices to be connected to a TV . Google should look at providing some kind of secondary storage access option. Say having a usb storage device connected to your TV having a video player app that gives an interface to these media contents is one use case I can think of.

Comment: I think the fact that Google TV add on is still based on 3.1 and there isn't an Add on release made for 3.2, that could be the reason for the missing sdcard support. 3.0 and 3.1 didn't have sdcard support. But what caught me by surprise was no local videoplayback support!!!